# django Manager not updating result

Tags: django, listview, django-generic-views

I have a weird problem with a ListView and a model Manager:
when reload the ListView, the results are not updated.

from models.py:

```
class TicketManager(models.Manager):
  def homepage(self):
      query = "select t.id, t.plant_id from maintenance_ticket as t order by t.id desc;"
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      cursor.execute(query)
      result_list = []
      for row in cursor.fetchall():
          p = self.model(
                  id = row[0],
                  plant_id=row[1], 
          )
          result_list.append(p)
      return result_list

class Ticket(models.Model):
  plant = models.ForeignKey(Impianto,verbose_name=_("Plant"))
  objects = TicketManager()
```

from views.py:

```
class TestTicketList(AclMixin,ListView):
    model = Ticket
    queryset = Ticket.objects.homepage()
    paginate_by = 25
    template_name = 'maintenance/skel_list.html'
```

### Premise:

with `python manage.py shell` everything is ok:

```
len(Ticket.objects.homepage())
```

always returns the correct number.

### The problem:

When I view the result via the `python manage runserver` (or via a website with "modwsgi"), the result is correct only the first time.

When I create some new instance of Ticket (via sql, via `shell`, via webserver), the ListView response is not updated, so I always get the Ticket list of the first run.

It seems that the query result is kindof "cached".

Elsewhere, on the same project, I use very similar model Manager, with very similar Listviews.

-- edited -- 
the template is not useful: it works everywherelse.

```
{% extends 'maintenance/base.html' %}
{% block mainbody %}
<table>
{% for item in object_list %}
<tr><td>{{item}}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you cache the template? also you don't need Model and Queryset, just use Queryset (since you need specific results) in the CBV.

Comment: no caching. same result after removing the "model" line.

Comment: can you paste the template code?

Comment: done, but it's not useful: the template is my generic template for list view.

Answer (score 2):

i don't understand why, but:

removing the `queryset` line from the ListView class

```
class TestTicketList(AclMixin,ListView):
    model = Ticket
    ### queryset = Ticket.objects.homepage()
    paginate_by = 25
    template_name = 'maintenance/skel_list.html'
```

and adding a method that just return the queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Ticket.objects.homepage()
```

seems to fix the problem.

```
--- pip freeze returns: ----
Django==1.6.5
Pillow==2.4.0
PyPDF2==1.20
South==0.8.4
Werkzeug==0.9.4
amqp==1.4.5
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.16
celery==3.1.9
django-bootstrap-toolkit==2.15.0
django-celery==3.1.9
-e git+https://github.com/theatlantic/django-chosen.git@3a912f73daf1091c07e10d76348b325491c20846#egg=django_chosen-master
django-debug-toolbar==1.0.1
django-email-templates==0.1
django-excel-response==1.0
django-excel-view==1.0
django-extensions==1.3.3
django-pyodbc==0.2.3
django-rosetta==0.7.4
django-stdimage==0.4.2
django-tables2==0.15.0
djorm-ext-pgbytea==0.5.0
html5lib==1.0b3
kombu==3.0.15
phpserialize==1.3
polib==1.0.4
pyodbc==3.0.7
pytz==2013.9
reportlab==3.0
six==1.6.1
sqlparse==0.1.11
xhtml2pdf==0.0.5
xlwt==0.7.5
```